# Multiple a row of data to a data table

Tags: pandas

I have two dfs. The tables look like:

```
  df1
              1    2      3    4
      Avg   0.21  0.13  0.5  0.24

  df2          1      2      3    4    
      2021    1.01  1.01   1.01  1.01 
      2022    1.02  1.01   1.01  1.02
      2023    1.02  1.02   1.03  1.02
      2024    1.01  1.01   1.01  1.01
```

I want to mul. row['Avg'] in df1 and rows from 2021 to 2014 in df2, so results should look like this:

```
 results 
                  1        2            3          4 
      2022    1.02*0.21  1.01*0.13   1.01*0.5  1.02*0.24
      2023    1.02*0.21  1.02*0.13   1.03*0.5  1.02*0.24
      2024    1.01*0.21  1.01*0.13   1.01*0.5  1.01*0.24
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df2.mul(df1.to_numpy(), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
           1       2      3       4
2021  0.2121  0.1313  0.505  0.2424
2022  0.2142  0.1313  0.505  0.2448
2023  0.2142  0.1326  0.515  0.2448
2024  0.2121  0.1313  0.505  0.2424
```

Comment: df2*df1.iloc[0] or df2.multiply(df1.iloc[0]) would work as well

Comment: Yes, iloc[0] does the same as to_numpy and probably works a bit faster.

Comment: The key is remember that pandas was to do intrinsic data alignment, so you need to strip that second dataframe of indexes by going to numpy array and then muliplying over axis 1.